# Issue configuring TCPDF on xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, config, tcpdf

I am currently trying to get `tcpdf` working on my website. I am using xampp as a localhost, but cannot seem to get the config files working correctly. I am almost certain my paths are pointing to the right directory in `tcpdf_config.php` but when I try and run a script on my `email.php` page, it is displaying the error shown below. I have tried playing around with pointing to the file/s in a number of ways, but to no avail.

When i navigate to the examples given in the TCPDF folder, they load and work fine, so not sure why i cannot get this page work. Any help much appreciated!

i have `tcpdf` installed in my xampp directory as follows:

`C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/ibill_v3/tcpdf`

**tcpdf_config.php**

```
<?php
//============================================================+
// File name   : tcpdf_config.php
// Begin       : 2004-06-11
// Last Update : 2014-12-11
//
// Description : Configuration file for TCPDF.
// Author      : Nicola Asuni - Tecnick.com LTD - www.tecnick.com - info@tecnick.com
// License     : GNU-LGPL v3 (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html)
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (C) 2004-2014  Nicola Asuni - Tecnick.com LTD
//
// This file is part of TCPDF software library.
//
// TCPDF is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
// under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
// published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the
// License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
// TCPDF is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
// WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
// See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
// along with TCPDF.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
//
// See LICENSE.TXT file for more information.
//============================================================+

/**
 * Configuration file for TCPDF.
 * @author Nicola Asuni
 * @package com.tecnick.tcpdf
 * @version 4.9.005
 * @since 2004-10-27
 */

// IMPORTANT:
// If you define the constant K_TCPDF_EXTERNAL_CONFIG, all the following settings will be ignored.
// If you use the tcpdf_autoconfig.php, then you can overwrite some values here.


/**
 * Installation path (/var/www/tcpdf/).
 * By default it is automatically calculated but you can also set it as a fixed string to improve performances.
 */
define ('K_PATH_MAIN', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/ibill_v3/tcpdf');

/**
 * URL path to tcpdf installation folder (http://localhost/tcpdf/).
 * By default it is automatically set but you can also set it as a fixed string to improve performances.
 */
define ('K_PATH_URL', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/ibill_v3/tcpdf');

/**
 * Path for PDF fonts.
 * By default it is automatically set but you can also set it as a fixed string to improve performances.
 */
//define ('K_PATH_FONTS', K_PATH_MAIN.'fonts/');

/**
 * Default images directory.
 * By default it is automatically set but you can also set it as a fixed string to improve performances.
 */
define ('K_PATH_IMAGES', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/ibill_v3/tcpdf/fonts');

/**
 * Deafult image logo used be the default Header() method.
 * Please set here your own logo or an empty string to disable it.
 */
//define ('PDF_HEADER_LOGO', '');

/**
 * Header logo image width in user units.
 */
//define ('PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH', 0);

/**
 * Cache directory for temporary files (full path).
 */
//define ('K_PATH_CACHE', '/tmp/');

/**
 * Generic name for a blank image.
 */
define ('K_BLANK_IMAGE', '_blank.png');

/**
 * Page format.
 */
define ('PDF_PAGE_FORMAT', 'A4');

/**
 * Page orientation (P=portrait, L=landscape).
 */
define ('PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION', 'P');

/**
 * Document creator.
 */
define ('PDF_CREATOR', 'TCPDF');

/**
 * Document author.
 */
define ('PDF_AUTHOR', 'TCPDF');

/**
 * Header title.
 */
define ('PDF_HEADER_TITLE', 'TCPDF Example');

/**
 * Header description string.
 */
define ('PDF_HEADER_STRING', "by Nicola Asuni - Tecnick.com\nwww.tcpdf.org");

/**
 * Document unit of measure [pt=point, mm=millimeter, cm=centimeter, in=inch].
 */
define ('PDF_UNIT', 'mm');

/**
 * Header margin.
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_HEADER', 5);

/**
 * Footer margin.
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER', 10);

/**
 * Top margin.
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_TOP', 27);

/**
 * Bottom margin.
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM', 25);

/**
 * Left margin.
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_LEFT', 15);

/**
 * Right margin.
 */
define ('PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT', 15);

/**
 * Default main font name.
 */
define ('PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN', 'helvetica');

/**
 * Default main font size.
 */
define ('PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN', 10);

/**
 * Default data font name.
 */
define ('PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA', 'helvetica');

/**
 * Default data font size.
 */
define ('PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA', 8);

/**
 * Default monospaced font name.
 */
define ('PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED', 'courier');

/**
 * Ratio used to adjust the conversion of pixels to user units.
 */
define ('PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO', 1.25);

/**
 * Magnification factor for titles.
 */
define('HEAD_MAGNIFICATION', 1.1);

/**
 * Height of cell respect font height.
 */
define('K_CELL_HEIGHT_RATIO', 1.25);

/**
 * Title magnification respect main font size.
 */
define('K_TITLE_MAGNIFICATION', 1.3);

/**
 * Reduction factor for small font.
 */
define('K_SMALL_RATIO', 2/3);

/**
 * Set to true to enable the special procedure used to avoid the overlappind of symbols on Thai language.
 */
define('K_THAI_TOPCHARS', true);

/**
 * If true allows to call TCPDF methods using HTML syntax
 * IMPORTANT: For security reason, disable this feature if you are printing user HTML content.
 */
define('K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML', false);

/**
 * If true and PHP version is greater than 5, then the Error() method throw new exception instead of terminating the execution.
 */
define('K_TCPDF_THROW_EXCEPTION_ERROR', false);

/**
 * Default timezone for datetime functions
 */
define('K_TIMEZONE', 'UTC');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

**email.php**

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

class ashPDF extends TCPDF {

public function Header() {

$this->setJPEGQuality(90);

$this->Image('logo.png', 62, 36, 72, 0, 'PNG', '/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png');

}

public function Footer() {

$this->SetY(-15);

$this->SetFont(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, 'I', 8);

$this->Cell(0, 10, 'php.refulz.com – Web Developer’s Blog', 0, false, 'C');

}

}

$pdf = new ashPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


// $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
 $pdf->SetAuthor('ash PHP');

$pdf->SetTitle('Fisrt PDF Document using TCPDF');

$pdf->SetSubject('ash PDF Example');

$pdf->SetKeywords('ash, TCPDF, PDF');

// add a page

$pdf->AddPage();
$col = 72; // Column size

$wideCol = 3 * $col;  // Description Column

$line = 18;  // Line height

// Table header

$pdf->SetFont( '', 'b' );

$pdf->Cell( $col, $line, 'S. No.', 1, 0, 'L' );

$pdf->Cell( $wideCol, $line, 'Task', 1, 0, 'L' );

$pdf->Cell( $col, $line, 'Time', 1, 0, 'R' );

$pdf->Ln(); // Adds Line break

// Table content beings here

$pdf->SetFont( '', '' );  // two parameters accept font-family and style. Passing blank sets default values

$counter = 1;   // Setting counter for S. No. column

foreach( $this->taskData['items'] as $item ) {

$pdf->Cell( $col, $line, $counter, 1, 0, 'L' );

$pdf->Cell( $wideCol, $line, $item[0], 1, 0, 'L' );

$pdf->Cell( $col, $line, $item[1], 1, 0, 'R' );

$pdf->Ln();

$counter++;

}

// Output the PDF document.

$pdf->Output( 'Tasksheet.pdf', 'D' );
?>
```

**Error Messages when trying to execute `email.php`:**

Warning: require_once(tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ibill_v3\html\email.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ibill_v3\html\email.php on line 2

Comment: In your _tcpdf_config.php_ have you tried to not define the paths as a fixed string like mentioned in the comments? And are you sure your relative paths in the _require_once_ statement pointing to your tcpdf-folder are correct?

Comment: When looking at the error message, i think the _require_once_ should point to * *../tcpdf/tcpdf.php**. I hope it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)